# How to fix error happened when using tensorflow in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When I using tensorflow-lite in Android, after change the model officially supported, An error happened

The input of my model has two inputs, 32*128*128*1 respectively, and I mimic the way to feed the inputs but failed

Here is some code in my project

```java
  @Override
  protected void processImage() {
    try {
      float[][][][] stft=readTxt("file:///android_asset/stft.txt");
      float[][][][] mfcc=readTxt("file:///android_asset/mfcc.txt");
      final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(stft, mfcc);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.print("can't get Bitmap");
    }

  }

  @Override
  public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final float[][][][] stft,final float[][][][] mfcc) {
    // Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

    Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
    // Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
    // on the provided parameters.
    LOGGER.i("begin run model");
    Trace.endSection(); // preprocessBitmap

    // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
    Trace.beginSection("feed");
    imgDatam.rewind();
    imgDatas.rewind();
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
      for(int j=0;j<128;j++){
        for(int k =0;k<128;k++){
          imgDatam.putFloat(mfcc[i][j][k][0]);
          imgDatas.putFloat(stft[i][j][k][0]);
        }

      }

    }

    outputClasses = new float[32][NUM_DETECTIONS];

    Object[] inputArray = {imgDatas,imgDatam};

    Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();

    outputMap.put(0, outputClasses);

    Trace.endSection();

    // Run the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("run");
    try{
      tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.i("finished");
    Trace.endSection();

    // Show the best detections.
    // after scaling them back to the input size.
    final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>(NUM_DETECTIONS);

    Trace.endSection(); // "recognizeImage"
    return recognitions;
  }
```

And the error shows:

> org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 23610 (mples.detection), pid 23610 (mples.detection)
>   ? A/DEBUG: pid: 23610, tid: 23610, name: mples.detection  >>> org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection <<<
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000001220b4  /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/lib/arm64/libtensorflowlite_jni.so
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000001216e4  /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/lib/arm64/libtensorflowlite_jni.so
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000001624ac  /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/lib/arm64/libtensorflowlite_jni.so
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000165974  /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/lib/arm64/libtensorflowlite_jni.so
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000000ed10  /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/lib/arm64/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_run+32)
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00000000001770ee  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run+158)
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00000000001768f6  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs+10)
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 0000000000007234  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage+1428) 
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 000000000000200e  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage+206)
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 000000000001d408  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.processImage+60)
>   ? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0000000000015c6a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kKVx47dAvHYDUZmU-_Wkag==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk (deleted) (org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onCreate+174)
>   ? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection': Connection refused

Thanks for your help anyway, I know this may be hard because I even can't find some guide about tensorflow lite

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue.  Where you able to find a solution?